# Adding a nan values to dataframe gives unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I want to insert `np.nan` to a `dataframe`; one `nan` for each row in random positions.
This is my `dataframe`:

```
list_cols= ['col01', 'col02', 'col03', 'col04', 'col05','col06', 'col07', 'col08', 'col09', 'col10','col11', 'col12', 'col13', 'col14', 'col15', 'col16']

X_full = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=1.0, high=100.0, size=(5,16)), columns=list(list_cols))
```

This is my code:

```
# Add a single nan value to each row
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
n_samples, n_features = X_full.shape
X_missing = X_full.copy()
missing_samples = np.arange(n_samples)
missing_features = rng.choice(n_features, n_samples, replace=True)
X_missing[missing_samples, missing_features] = np.nan
```

It returns `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'`.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do

```py
X_missing = X_full.copy()
indexes = np.random.choice(range(X_missing.shape[1]), X_missing.shape[0])
X_missing.values[range(X_missing.shape[0]), indexes] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not 100% sure I understand your question correctly, in case you just want to change the value of a single cell into NaN (i.e. values at (0, 12) & (1, 7) etc should be nan) then you can use:

```
for row, column in zip(missing_samples, missing_features):
    X_missing.iat[row, column] = np.nan
```

Note that we use a method starting with an 'i': `.iat`. This means the change we are applying is based on an **I**ndex and not on a row/column name.

In your example you get an error because it interprets `missing_samples` and `missing_features` as row names and column names, but the values you gave were number (namely the indices). You could use `.iloc` to clarify that what you are giving is an index and not a name but then it will be replacing whole rows, that's why I use `.iat` because I assume you only want to replace values '*at*' specific '*i* ndices'. Hope this helps